# Finding equivalence over a matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, logic

```
 X  11 22 33 44 55 66

 11 1  0  0  0  1  0

 22 0  1  0  1  0  1

 33 0  0  1  0  0  0

 44 0  1  0  1  0  1

 55 1  0  0  0  1  0

 66 0  1  0  1  0  1

|A| = 6, 

A = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66}

B = { (22,22), (22,44), (44,22), (44,44), (44,66), (66,66), (66,22), (22,66), (66,44), (33,33),
    (11,55), (55,11), (11,11), (55,55) }
```

this is my matrix i know that in order to find equivalence i need to make sure first that i have a reflexive,symmetric and transitive ratios, i cant figure out how to connect the 3 of them to find the equivalence in the matrix.
i believe that the right naming for that will be the "Departments of equality"

any pointers will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite this in a better way:
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
& 11 & 22 & 33 & 44 & 55 & 66 \\
\hline
11 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
22 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
44 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
55 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
66 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
where a $1$ means that the pair (row index,column index) belongs to the relation, $0$ otherwise.

The relation is clearly reflexive and symmetric. In order to be an equivalence relation, consider, for each element, the set
$$
[x]=\{y:(x,y)\in B\}
$$
Then
\begin{align}
[11]&=\{11,55\}\\
[22]&=\{22,44,66\}\\
[33]&=\{33\}\\
[44]&=\{22,44,66\}=[22]\\
[55]&=\{11,55\}=[11]\\
[66]&=\{22,44,66\}=[22]
\end{align}
So the relation partitions $A=\{11,22,33,44,55,66\}$ into disjoint sets. So…

Comment: Thank you for the answer now i need to translate this in to code :)